# How to avoid computed property to get translation?

Tags: ember.js

This is current solution.

filters/index.hbs

```
{{view App.CardFilterView labelTranslation="filter.provider.label" controllerBinding="controllers.cardProviders"
filterName="provider"}}

{{view App.CardFilterView labelTranslation="filter.rewards.label" controllerBinding="controllers.cardRewards"
filterName="rewards"}}
```

card_filter.hbs

```
<h3>{{view.label}}</h3>
{{view Ember.Select  contentBinding="content" optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.name"
classNames="multiselect" multiple="multiple"}}
```

CardFilterView

```
  label: (->
    Ember.I18n.t @get('labelTranslation')
  ).property('labelTranslation')
```

Can I somehow go without computed property and do something like this:

`<h3>{{t view.label}}</h3>`? (this of course doesn't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is by defining a handlebars helper to do the job.

Something like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('i18n', function(key) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(Ember.I18n.t(key))
});
```

And then use it like so:

```
<h3>{{i18n view.label}}</h3>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of old thread and this was feature was not implemented at the answer.

```
  #### Translate attributes on a plain tag:
  <a {{translateAttr title="button.add_user.title">text</a>
```

This is from the ember-i18n documentation since v1.6.0 (2014-02-06).

Thank you changelog.